# Adding Gear/Transmission oil to a Kubota L2202?

Tags: oil, tractor

The 3 point linkage raising & lowering on my Kubota L2202 tractor is not working very well, it's hard to shift, and does not seem to raise to full height.

So I checked the transmission oil by opening the oil plug, and there's some oil in it, but only about 1/3 full.

There doesn't seem to be any sort of dipstick for the transmission oil level.  How do I know how much oil to add (if any), and what sort of oil should I add.

[image: oil plug]  [image: oil hole]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Most side view type fill holes like this use the bottom of the hole itself as the "full" level. Not sure if it's the case here, but seems feasible. Please don't take my word for it. Hopefully someone has some experience with your tractor. As far as the type of oil, I bet it's just gear oil. You could take a whiff of it and if it just smells terrible (not burnt, but just really obnoxious oil smell), it's probably 75W90 gear oil.

Comment: Checking around at other Kubota tractors, it seems they may use a sight glass. Look around on the exterior of the transmission and see if there is a small (around an inch or so in diameter) glass piece placed in the side of the transmission somewhere. The fluid must be within the visual range of the glass in order for it to be "at level".